# "to make a tired point": is it an idiom?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the expression "to make a tired point" mean? For example in this sentence:

> To make a tired point, which one of us is truly crazy?

(It is from an episode of *The Simpsons*. [Read the script](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/7F24.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is used as a statement, it means the point is *already* known but again raised. And due to this, it'll be a *boring point.*

The word in concern is the adjective *tired.*

> [tired](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tired?q=tired): *(Especially of a statement or idea) boring or uninteresting because overfamiliar*

So, here, who is 'truly crazy' is a tired point because they already know that! It's just that the ***familiar*** question is raised again.

Answer (score 2):

A *tired point* is one that has been repeatedly raised.

The act of addressing the same point over and over again is sometimes called [beating a dead horse](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Beating-a-Dead-Horse.html); the actual point that is being raised over and over again is the "tired point."

> **Bill**: I think we should buy new printers for the office.
>   **Ted**: Bill, you're beating a dead horse. We already told you: there's not enough money in the budget.
>
> **Bill**: I think we should buy new printers for the office.
>   **Ted**: Bill, that's a tired point. We already told you: there's not enough money in the budget.

It's an understandable phrase, but I don't think it's all that commonly used.